# How to open a NSWindow with a "popup" animation

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, animation, nswindow

I'd like to create something like this window:
http://cl.ly/1m2a2w3P2D20 (click on "view in your browser")

I don't know where to start. Is it a custom "animator" or something like that?
How can Any ideas on how to perform something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On 10.7 and above, if you call -setAnimationBehavior: the window will automatically animate this or several other ways when you -orderFront: or -makeKeyAndOrderFront:. I believe the behavior you want is [NSWindowAnimationBehaviorAlertPanel](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000013-SW155).

Comment: Bonus round: You can set this in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick update for those that are looking for it in Interface Builder

1. Select The Dropdown below your Window
2. Select Window
   [image: Interfacebuilder Window Dropdown]
3. In the right panel you have a list of settings including "Animation"
   [image: Animation Dropdown in properties panel]